# Having a TableRow with TextView's underneath each other

Tags: java, android

I'm currently having the following problem:

I've got a TableView that is given TableRow's to be added to it with data. I want each TableRow to contain 2 TextView's having a width of the parent and are underneath each other, for example:

```
| TextView1.............. |
| TextView2.............. |
| .........EndOfTextView2 |
```

In my example above, it's just showing that I also want the second TextView to be able to run over multiple lines.

Here is the XML for my TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
      android:id="@+id/feed"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_margin="5px"
      android:stretchColumns="1"
>
</TableLayout>
```

Used to iOS so I'm kind of new in this XML/Java style mobile programming department.

**EDIT:**

I ended up adding a LinearLayout to the TableRow, is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to do it:

- Adding a vertical LinearLayout to each row is one.
- Another option is not to use a TableLayout, but do everything with a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).
- A third one is to use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) instead of a TableLayout (since, as it looks like, you're using just one cell per row).

The links above are for the android site tutorials for `ListView` and `RelativeLayout`.

Pros/Cons:

- The first option is the easiest to implement, but is not really efficient.
- The second one has the advantage of using less layouts, thus increasing performance and reducing memory usage, but it will take some time to get it right.
- The third one is the most flexible if the rows will be changing dynamically. The con is that it would require a custom adapter for your two lines of text (adding a little complexity to your first program).

Comment: I ended up using a LinearLayout as it will be using a number of items within each row in the future. Thanks